# How to detect the height of part of a image?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

[image]

**Sometimes the doctor doesn't flatten it.What I want to do is checking whether it is not flat**.
I use a canny algorithm to handle it.

```
// Example 2-7. The Canny edge detector writes its output to a single-channel (grayscale) image
// 2
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void help(char** argv) {
    std::cout << "\n"
        << "\nExample 2-7. The Canny edge detector writes its output to a single-channel (grayscale) image"
        << "\nCall:\n"
        << argv[0] << " <path/image>\n"
        << "For example:\n"
        << argv[0] << " ../fruits.jpg\n"
        << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        help(argv);
        return 0;
    }

    cv::Mat img_rgb, img_gry, img_cny;

    cv::namedWindow("Example Gray", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::namedWindow("Example Canny", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    img_rgb = cv::imread(argv[1]);

    cv::cvtColor(img_rgb, img_gry, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::imshow("Example Gray", img_gry);

    cv::Canny(img_gry, img_cny, 10, 100, 3, true);
    cv::imshow("Example Canny", img_cny);

    cv::waitKey(0);

}
```

Then the picture changes like this.
[image]

What should I do next?

I updated the code by adding as follows:

```
Rect rect(150, 0, 600, 300);
Mat image_roi = img_rgb(rect);
```

[image]

### Then use contour to get the top?
Is there any solution like template matching or something else because the photo took by the camera may have a slightly difference.

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Rect rect(150, 0, 600, 300);
Mat image_roi = img_rgb(rect);

```
cv::cvtColor(image_roi, img_gry, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::imshow("Example Gray", img_gry);

cv::blur(img_gry, img_blr, cv::Size(3, 3));
cv::imshow("Example blur", img_blr);

cv::Canny(img_blr, img_cny, 10, 100, 3, true);
cv::imshow("Example Canny", img_cny);

vector<Vec2f> lines;
HoughLines(img_cny, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 180, 0, 0);
```

The threshold here is difficult to determine.

Comment: What gets "flattened"? And what are you trying to measure?

Comment: Gets "flattened" means every tube as tall as the others.See in the picture, one tube is in a bad position.What I'm trying to measure is to find it out.

Comment: I think you may want ot blur it a little before running `cv::Canny`, like, `cv::Mat img_blr; cv::blur(img_gry, img_blr, cv::Size(3, 3));` to remove artifacts from the reflections (and then use `img_blr` instead of `img_gry` with `cv::Canny`). [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNZ2K.png) - I don't know OpenCV well enough to know where to go from there though.

Comment: You know the ideal height of tubes in a flattened condition. If background is fix plane white then scan for pixel existance above some threshold height. This can be done by searching for pixels. But the background width can be increased. So, the window or lamp should not come in picture.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Search for contours on the Canny image. Iterate through them and search for the highest point. If that point is higher than the thresholded value you set then it is not "flattened".

Comment: 2 ideas. (1) [Template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html) to find the tops of the test tubes. This may not work that well because the tops towards the back are smaller than the tops in the front. (2) Use [Hough Lines](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) to identify the tops of the test tubes. For this you would want to isolate the test tubes rack from the rest of the scene.

Comment: That may work most of the time.But when the camera becomes the part of an automated workflow, the picture sometimes will as a whole gets taller or lower.Then only detecting the top may not work.Detecting the relative position maybe a good idea. But I don't know how to  distinguish the top of the rack.

Comment: I have no prior experience in doing things like that but if you imagine scan-lines, a few pixels high, you could perhaps do an overlapping scan from top to bottom (in that black area above the tubes) until you get some white. If you get "enough" white, all are equally high.

Comment: What I've recently done is to get a HoughLine after canny.After that I use the FAST algorithm to find out the top y.Then if the dif between HoughLine and the top y is out of the threshold, I know it is not 'flattened'. The cost time is about 0.3s.

Comment: @pigeonson That sounds like a feasable way. Did you blur before running canny (which I think will make it a little cleaner)? Do you get the Hough lines for a particular area of the picture for for the complete picture?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I blur it before running canny.Getting the Hough lines is not for the complete picture,it is after the rect because there will be many Hough lines using the complete picture. I did the 'rect' action not containing the rack,see the last picture. But it causes a new problem.The Hough line is on the top of the normal tubes.What will happen if there is only a tube or most of the tubes not in a line?It will not work.Including the rack may be a good idea.But I don't know how to distinguish the Hough lines wich is the one I need.

Comment: Perhaps you can show a picture with the Hough lines painted out too?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The pictures were uploaded.

Comment: Ok, that looks difficult. I was hoping that the Hough lines would be one line per tube (top). It's a bit hard to see though since you have the same color for the Hough lines as the contours, but I guess that's because it's in b/w?

Comment: @TedLyngmo How to make the Hough lines be one line per tube?Will the background mixed in or do a rect with no background?How about the rack, It contains the Hough lines too.

Comment: I'm not sure unfortunately. :(